# ERROR: Application requires API version 18. Device API version is 17 (Android 4.2.2)

Tags: java, android, api

In my Google map Project ERROR: Application requires API version 18. Device API version is 17 (Android 4.2.2). message shows in console.
please anyone tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Change the API level to 18.

Comment: Change the min sdk version inside  manifest

Comment: Post The Mainfest file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your minSDKVersion:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="17"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: Hey Sagar I have encountered the same problem. For me the minSDK was 17 and my device was API 15. So I changed the manifest to say android:minSdkVersion="15". but the error persists  Do you might have an idea what to do?

Comment: I tried to clean and rebuild even to close and re-close eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Check your manifest file. Give like this

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If in your code you don't use methods added in API 18 you can modify your AndroidManifest like this : 
android:minSdkVersion="17"

Otherwise you can't install you application in device with API 17.